# Access JQuery from Controller or Route

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have next structure:

- builder.hbs (template)
- builder.js (route)
- builder.js (controller)

I want to execute some jQuery code when template will be rendered. I found old solutions with View and didInsertElement, but I don't have View in this case. So, is it possible to execute jQuery code from route or controller?

jQuery code:

```
this.$("#filtersMenu").fixedsticky();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `didInsertElement` on the view of the controller. If say you have `IndexController` then in `views/index.js` you would have:

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    this.$('#filtersMenu').fixedsticky();
    this._super();
  }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kegere/1/edit?html,js,output besides that globally jQuery is always on `Ember.$`:

```
Ember.$('#filtersMenu').fixedsticky();
```

That said you should consider putting this into a component that's entirely responsible for rendering it.

Comment: I added `didInsertElement: function() {
  console.log("didInsertElement");
 }` to controller but I see nothing in console log.

Comment: @Crabar Ah sorry I got myself confused. What happens is that the controller implicitly has a view which you can override. I've expanded my answer and added a jsfiddle.

Comment: I don't have views in my app. As I understand I can create it but as I know Views are deprecated now and have been removed in version 2.0.

Comment: @Crabar Controllers are removed in 2.0, which is what you're asking about and you do have views in your app, they are implicit just as you have a controller for your route, you have a view for your controller. The JSFiddle has a working example.

Comment: It's working but there is deprecation warning in console log. So if I will update to 2.0 this approach will not work. And ObjectController and ArrayController are deprecated but not regular controllor for route. Is there a solution that works without deprecation messages?

Comment: @Crabar There are no routable components yet (which is the last piece needed before controllers are completely removed). There is no *reasonable* way that I know of to have route specific DOM manipulation from inside of the route/controller but you can wait for `afterRender`. If you want to stop using `ArrayController` or `ObjectController` you can move on to using components in your templates instead. You also have `didInsertElement` on components. That's what I'd use, but it's not specific to any route, it's specific to wherever you've placed the component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86868/discussion-between-crabar-and-kit-sunde).